# How to overcome POST request 404 error in C#?

Tags: c#, http-post

I'm getting this error on running the c# code to make a POST request to an API. I'm able to make a successful get request but am failing to make a POST request. I'm running the code as C# console app on visual studio.

Would be happy to know if I'm missing anything in making the POST request.

**error:**

```
StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Wed, 15 Jul 2020 03:40:57 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  ETag: "5ea1d6db-6486"
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 25734
}
```

**POST request function - definition:**

```
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostInstantTestAsync(InstantTestItem test)
        {
            var url = $"https://someAPI?format=json";
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            return await client.PostAsync(url, stringContent);
        }
```

**POST function call, and printing response:**

```
            InstantTestItem test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InstantTestItem>(JSONdata);
            var response = await PostInstantTestAsync(test);
            var testDetails = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.Out.WriteLine(testDetails);
```

Comment: Without information what would be valid request (returning 20x) it is not possible to help. Most common issue is not to provide body to POST request but it is not the case here - so we need debugging details, ideally in form of [MCVE] with both client and server code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I found the bugs with my code

1. Was passing incorrect url for API endpoint -> clearing that gave me 400 error(bad request).
2. The 400 error was due to incorrect object handling(incorrect json object), correcting that I was able to make a successful request.